# Why does window.location.href not showing the hash in IE

Tags: javascript, hash

```
window.location.href = 'www.mysite.com/testpage/#12';
```

In Chrome and Firefox the user is redirected to www.mysite.com/testpage/#12 successfuly, However in IE the user is directed to www.mysite.com/testpage/ without the hash, how can I force the browser to read the hash?

UPDATE:

Here's the actual code:

```
window.location.href = siteurl+'?selection/'+edu_year_selectionreal+'/'+semester_selectionreal+'/'+subject_selectionreal+'#?selection/'+edu_year_selectionreal+'/'+semester_selectionreal+'/'+subject_selectionreal+'/'+edu_year_selectiontitle+'/'+semester_selectiontitle+'/'+subject_selectiontitle;
```

in IE it stops reading starting from (#?)

Comment: Does not work in IE6, works fine in IE7+.

Comment: I've successfully tested it in IE 9.0.8112.16421 on Windows 7. Is the page (HTTP 3XX) redirecting anything?

Comment: I made an edit in the question, please read it.

Comment: That is fundamentally equal to `location.href = 'http://stackoverflow.com/#Test';'. Have you ensured that the page you're requesting does not redirect?

Comment: No it doesn't redirect, and it's working fine on chrome and firefox, the problem is only with IE

Comment: Found the bug siteurl+'?selection/' should be siteurl+'/?selection/' with an extra '/' between the two parts of the URL

Answer (score 0):

Found the bug:
`siteurl+'?selection/` should be `siteurl+'/?selection/` with an extra '/' between the two parts of the URL